# "Come back just now to continue reviewing"?

Tags: bug, review-queues, rate-limiting

I just won a

> Thank you for reviewing 20 suggested edits today; come back just now to continue reviewing.

Really? :)  What did I trip over?

Comment: the counter for daily review limits was 2 minutes ago. I guess you got it timed perfectly :p

Comment: You can come back after you read that text.

Comment: @TLama: Yeah.  It's pretty unusual wording, though---"come back at this point in the recent past to continue reviewing."

Comment: It must be displayed *in the past*. It is you, who is reading it *just now* :)

Comment: asynchronous events *will* lead to race conditions...

Comment: @BenVoigt: Hmm.  Is duration-to-words translation done on the client?  I've never looked.

Answer (score 55, accepted):

This is a [known bug](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/224685/daily-vote-limit-reached-vote-again-just-now) in the relative timestamp system. It only happens [1/86400](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=number+of+seconds+in+a+day) of the time (or about a 1/9 the probability that you'll be struck by lightning in your lifetime), so it's not exactly high-priority.

Comment: Not high priority?  That is bull-****.  I demand an accurate relative timestamp more than 99.99884259% of the time.

Comment: Note for later : if this happens 9 times you better never go out if there's heavy rain with lightning. :)

Comment: @AndréDaniel: Wha?  Is there something special about events which happen `pow(86400,-8)/9` times as frequently as being struck by lightning?

Comment: @BenVoigt "about 1/9 the probability that you'll be struck by lightning" it was a reference to that... not sure if I'm right though.

Comment: @AndréDaniel And that's exactly how probability works ;) ... cue xkcd

Comment: @AndréDaniel No. What Undo is saying is that every time this happens, you get struck with lightning nine times.

Comment: 1/3000 chance of being struck by lightning in your lifetime in the US according to Nat Geo: http://news.nationalgeographic.com/news/2004/06/0623_040623_lightningfacts.html
1/6250 according to National Weather Service...   so depending on how many days you hit your review limit, a lightning strike could be quite a bit more likely.

Comment: @ArtjomB http://xkcd.com/1252/

Comment: In South Africa, "just now" is an arbitrary time in the future, anywhere from 10 minutes to 10 hours. So I think it's fine. http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/just_now

Comment: @Salgar Good thing we're all South Africans then, eh? :-P